# launching open gl es application from windows service

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to launch an open gl es texture shading application from a windows service using CreateProcessAsUser API. It launches but the texture rendering doesn't happen and it crashes after some time.
On the other hand if I create a normal C console application and use CreateProcess API, it works fine.

Suggest what can be the possible error here.

Comment: If you are going to ask for help, at least some information about what you have actually done would be useful. "I've written some unknown software which crashes" isn't exactly something we can help with without psychic powers =)

Answer (score 0):

Processes launched as services normally don't have access to a GPU. More importantly if you don't jump a few extra hoops (create and use a FBO, or use a PBuffer) without a window visible, OpenGL drawing commands will not generate pixels.